# dynamic imagebutton wrap_content doesn't wrap_content

Tags: android, imagebutton

I've created an android imagebutton with code and add an image source to it.
The layoutparams of the imagebutton are wrap_content

```
`LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
public ImageButton createActionBarItem(int id, int img, String tag){
ImageButton btnImage = new ImageButton(context);
btnImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
btnImage.setImageResource(img);
btnImage.setId(id);
btnImage.setTag(tag);
return btnImage;
}`
```

The problem I experience is that the imagebackground (even the default background) is smaller than the imageResource
Any idea to make the imageButtonBackground stretch so that the drawable fits in?

Comment: where do you store your bitmap ? maybe your device is hdpi and you've put bitmap only into mdpi, or ldpi directory - in this case image will be downscaled

Comment: it's only in my hdpi directory and my device is mdpi, don't think that should be the problem because i can clearly see the image go outside of the border of the background
I fixed the problem (or at least used a workaround): I know place my imagedrawable in the background of the button and place that in a relativelayout which I give the original background